# Python script throws ValueError while plotting data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have tried an example from the page 11 of [tephigramDocs](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/tephi/stable/tephi.pdf), but it raises a `ValueError`. The code is the following:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os.path
import tephi
dew_point = os.path.join(tephi.DATA_DIR, ’dews.txt’)
dew_data = tephi.loadtxt(dew_point, column_titles=(’pressure’, ’dewpoint’))
dews = zip(dew_data.pressure, dew_data.dewpoint)
tpg = tephi.Tephigram()
tpg.plot(dews)
plt.show()
```

Clearly the format of data passed to the plot function is wrong but I cannot find a solution for this. The error message is:

```
ValueError: The environment profile data requires to be a sequence of pressure, temperature value pairs.
```

Comment: We're not visiting other links for your code. Please post it here.

Comment: This error seems to pertain to the Tephi module and the data you are using to create the "dews" data.  Only someone knowledgeable in Tephi will be able to help you here.

Comment: Try `tpg.plot(list(dews))`. From the error message it looks like it expects a list or an array instead of a generator.

Comment: thanks @xg.plt.py it worked .